# Get http request request parameter value

Tags: java, rest, servlets, captcha, recaptcha

I am calling `Restful web service` via `ajax` call. On this page i have `google recaptcha` whose parameter passing via get httprequest parameter. In rest service, i am getting http request object via `@Context` but it's returning null for both parameter.
How to resolve this issue

Comment: I don't quite understand who is calling whom and what code is under your control. Please provide more details.

Comment: please post some code to understand where is problem.

Comment: How are you passing - in headers or in httprequest ???